# Multiple Marker Strange Click Issue : Google Map API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm able to implement multiple markers by using the following code:

```
<?php foreach($dummy as $cid=>$data)
{   ?>
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data['lat']; ?>,<?php echo $data['lon']; ?>); 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: "<?php echo $data['name']; ?>"
    });
    icons[j] = marker;
    maps[0] = map;    
    j++;
<?php  
}   
?>  
for(var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
{       
   google.maps.event.addListener(icons[i], 'click', function(){
    markerClick(icons[i], maps[0]); // this is the problem area
    // markerClick(icons[0], maps[0]); // this works
    // markerClick(icons[1], maps[0]); // so does this
   });  
}   

function markerClick(marker_argument, map){     
    console.log(marker_argument);        
 }
```

The issue is with the `google.maps.event.addListener` function. If I use the variable `i`, then `markerClick()`'s `console.log()` returns *undefined*. However if I use a hardcoded value (1, 2, or 3), `console.log()` returns the marker object.

What baffles me is why the argument is not being passed if I use the loop variable `i`, but works if I hardcode a value. What am I missing here?

Comment: Stab in the dark.. Have you tried wrapping the `.addListener` loop in a JavaScript `function(){}`? If not, read up about closures and then try.

Comment: Yep. Closures was the key. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad I could help. Added it as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `.addListener` loop in a JavaScript closure, and it should work!